# Heroku server returns Html for an json object?

Tags: python, heroku

I was making an python app when I encountered an problem

This url http://instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1 returns the json data of anyones Instagram profile page whether it's private or public with python requests.get() method. But when I upload my app to heroku the same url retrievs an html file saying

**webpage not available**

But the code runs normally in my local machine . Any suggestions will be of huge help

Comment: Can you post your code where you make the GET request ?

Comment: I suspect Instagram is blocking requests originating from Heroku-hosted apps. There might be a setting within Heroku or a proxy server you can use to prevent this.

Comment: `re=requests.get(url).json()` (First time this code gave an error in heroku logs so i changed it to get text and write it to a file, there i saw it was getting a html page insted of json